# (installshield 2010) Conditional features selection

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010, basic-msi

(Basic MSI Project)

I would like to deselect parent feature automatically when all children are deselected, but i can`t find any option for that on installshield IDE.

For example,
(feature select dialog)

Feature A
---Feature A-1
---Feature A-2

If A-1 and A-2 are deselected by user, I want A also to be deselected automatically.

How can I do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's nothing in the built in UI control that does this.  The thought is a feature isn't always empty, it could have components of it's own.  If it doesn't have components then it won't get registered as installed anyways.

You might be able to use conditional control events on the Back and Next Buttons to create the relationship using the Remove control event but you won't see it refresh in the UI right away.

[Control Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)